# Solving 2D pde $\Delta u(x,y) = u^{\alpha}(y,x)$ numerically

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'am trying to solve this 2d pde on $ [-1,1]^2$
$$\Delta u(x,y) = u^{\alpha}(y,x)$$
note that in the rhs $u$ is evaluated at $(y,x)$  which we can consider as a deviation $u\circ \theta(x,y)$ where $\theta(x,y) = (y,x)$. 
I used a uniform discretization and got: 
$$  \frac{u_{i-1,j} - 2u_{i,j} + u_{i+1,j}   }{\Delta x^2} + \frac{u_{i,j-1} - 2u_{i,j} + u_{i,j+1} }{\Delta x^2}  = u^{\alpha}_{j,i} $$

As an example we can take $\alpha = 1/2$ and BC: $u(\pm1,y) = 0,   u(x, \pm1) = 1$
I don't see how to generate the system of equations and corresponding matrix.
Any help or other method to investigate is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The l.h.s. is linear and can be rewritten as $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}$, where $\mathbf A$ is a matrix and $\mathbf u$ is the vector of unknowns. The r.h.s. is nonlinear and it reads $\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{u}')$ where $\mathbf r$ is the vector-valued exponentiation function with power $\alpha$. The prime $'$ denotes the deviation that maps $u_{i,j} \mapsto u_{j,i}$, which is equivalent to transposition in matrix representation. Now, you have to solve
$$
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{r}(\mathbf{u}') \, ,
$$
e.g. by using Newton's method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The r.h.s is $(u(y, x))^{\alpha}$ so $r$ is the composite of an exponentiation function with a deviation $\theta(x,y) = (y, x)$. Is it possible to solve it numerically with Matlab with additional BC?

Comment: @Clifford Fixed! Yes, numerical resolution can be performed the same way.

Comment: It may be more computationally efficient to use an ADI (Alternating Direction Implicit) scheme rather than using a direct solver. You could also set it up as a transient problem and solve it until you reach a steady state using the Peaceman-Rachford ADI approach.

Comment: Thanks @Harry49 and Sharat, I'll try to explore your suggestions.

Comment: Since $\alpha = 1/n$ where $n$ is a positive integer, Is it more efficient to solve  numerically $(Au)^n = u^T$ ?

Comment: @Clifford I'm not sure if that makes a true difference. However, be aware that solutions may not be unique. Indeed, already in the scalar case, $(A u)^n = u$ may have multiple solutions.